# Loop DataFrame Production

Tags: r, loops, subset

I'm looking to break down a large data frame (`mix1a.df`) into many smaller ones (eg. `drugA.df`, `drugB.df`, `drugC.df` etc) in an automated (loop) fashion. How can I have R automatically create a subset dataframe for each type of drug it finds (n drugs in list = n dataframes) within the initial dataframe `mix1a.df`?

For example, right now I extract the information I want for a single data frame in the following way:

```
alprazolam.df<-subset(mix1a.df, mix1a.df$Component.name.x == "Alprazolam", 
select=c("Sample.Name", "Component.name.x", "TCAmount", "Ratio"))
alprazolam.df$Sample.Name<-(as.character)(alprazolam.df$Sample.Name)
alprazolam.df$Ratio<-(as.numeric)(alprazolam.df$Ratio)
alprazolam.df$Sample.Name.Level <- substr(alprazolam.df$Sample.Name, 1,2)
alprazolam.df$Sample.Name.Level<-(as.factor)(alprazolam.df$Sample.Name.Level)
```

Ideally in the process of automating this the class type will also be converted as shown in the code above.

For some example data:

`Sample.Name    Component.name  TCAmount  Ratio
1A-S0          Alprazolam         0.0      0.05
1A-S1          Alprazolam         1.5      0.07
1A-S2          Alprazolam         3.1      0.08
1A-S3          Alprazolam         6.25     0.10
2A-S0          Alprazolam         0.0      0.06
2A-S1          Alprazolam         1.5      0.08
2A-S2          Alprazolam         3.1      0.09
2A-S3          Alprazolam         6.25     0.10
1B-S0          Alprazolam         0.0      0.05
1B-S1          Alprazolam         1.5      0.08
1B-S2          Alprazolam         3.1      0.10
1B-S3          Alprazolam         6.25     0.11
1A-S0          Codeine            0.0      0.10
1A-S1          Codeine            1.5      0.30
1A-S2          Codeine            3.1      0.41
1A-S3          Codeine            6.25     0.62
2A-S0          Codeine            0.0      0.09
2A-S1          Codeine            1.5      0.29
2A-S2          Codeine            3.1      0.40
2A-S3          Codeine            6.25     0.62
1B-S0          Codeine            0.0      0.09
1B-S1          Codeine            1.5      0.28
1B-S2          Codeine            3.1      0.41
1B-S3          Codeine            6.25     0.61`

Comment: Can you provide any example data?
I would do a for-loop based on the unique values of the drugs, and then save it in a list. This list would then contain all of the different data frames.

Comment: Use `split` for this.

Comment: Example data has been added. Sorry - I should have thrown that in up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split is useful but I found it hard to do calculations on the data buried in the `dataframe_list` afterwards. I found that if I created a column called `Sample.Name.Level` to generate "AlprazolamA1" for example using:

`df$Sample.Name.Level<-substr(df$Sample.Name, 1,2)`

Then I could make a for loop using:

`analytes<-unique(as.factor(df$Component.name)) 
df.names<-unique(as.character(df$Component.name))
for (i in 1:nlevels(analytes)) {
loop.df<-subset(df, df$Component.name == analytes [i], loop.df$Sample.Name.Levelselect=c("Sample.Name.Level", "Component.name", "TCAmount", "Ratio"))
    loop.df$Sample.Name.Level<-(as.character)(loop.df$Sample.Name.Level)
    loop.df$Ratio<-(as.numeric)(loop.df$Ratio)
    try(plot(loop.df$TCAmount, loop.df$Ratio))
    try(abline(loop.df))
    assign(df.names2[i], loop.df)}`

Which then also assigns at the end the analyte name to the subsetted dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

In a fully reproducible example you could use:

```
  component <- c("A", "B", "C")
  value <- c(1, 2, 3)
  test <- data.frame(component, value)

  dataframe_list <- split(test, component)
```

You can then access the different components using (for example) `dataframe_list$A`. Alternatively and more manually could use:

```
  dataframe_list <- list()

  for(comp in test$component){
    dataframe_list[[length(dataframe_list)+ 1]] <-  test[which(test$component == comp),]
  }
```

Which will put all of the different sub `data.frames` in a list but without easy access per component.